# Build the matching option for jQuery UI Droppable's Intersect tolerance

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I want to drag an element into TWO OR MORE droppable areas, but those droppable areas need to be wholly contained within my draggable object.

The problem is, none of [jQuery UI's existing functionality for droppable tolerances](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance) meets this need.

Ideally I'd use "intersect", but where the the draggable and droppable object measurements are reversed in the code.  (This logic can be found in `jquery-ui.js` by searching for `$.ui.intersect`.)

I have tried overriding that function by [duck punching with jQuery](https://www.paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/) and tried setting the `tolerance` to a custom function like this:

```
tolerance: function(draggable, droppable) {
            if(!droppable.offset) return false;

            return ...logic check here...
        },
        drop: ...continues...
```

Neither worked.

Here is a JSFiddle to illustrate what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/myingling/kgaqb0ay/5/

Again, all Items //covered// by a person should be assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifying **$.ui.intersect** seems to be the best approach. You have different options. If you don't need that much flexibility, you can simply add a **tolerance** type, 'cover' for example. Then you just need to add a case to the switch that checks the tolerance type in **intersect**, which can be precisely the inverse of 'fit'. Like this:

```
  case 'fit':
    return (l <= x1 && x2 <= r && t <= y1 && y2 <= b);
    break;
  case 'cover':
    return (l >= x1 && x2 >= r && t >= y1 && y2 >= b);
    break;
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/6nyqja4a/4/

Or if you want more flexibility, you add a case where **tolerance** is a function. Then you can pass a function in the option, which allows you to have precise tolerance for different droppable. Something like this for example:
In **interserct** function:

```
 if (toleranceMode instanceof Function) {

    return toleranceMode(draggable, droppable, x1, x2, y1, y2, l, r, t, b);

  } else {
    switch (toleranceMode) {
      case 'fit':
        return (l <= x1 && x2 <= r && t <= y1 && y2 <= b);
        break;
...
```

And you call it like this:

```
$('.droppable').droppable({
  hoverClass: "yellow",
  tolerance: function(drag, drop, x1, x2, y1, y2, l, r, t, b) {
    return (l >= x1 && x2 >= r && t >= y1 && y2 >= b);
  },
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $("#value_" + $(this).data("id")).val(ui.draggable.data("id"));
    console.log("Item " + $(this).data("id") + " taken by " + ui.draggable.data("id"));
  }
});
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/h4wm3r09/3/

From jquery 1.12 **$.ui.intersect** function is scoped so that it cannot be directly modified afterwards. It is called in **$.ui.ddmanager** as a local variable, so even if you modify **$.ui.intersect**, it won't be used. Customizing it is a bit more complex. You can do it this way, basically you rescope **intersect** and then redefine **drag** and **drop** method on **$.ui.ddmanager** so that it calls the modified intersect:

```
var intersect = $.ui.intersect = ( function() {
    function isOverAxis( x, reference, size ) {
        return ( x >= reference ) && ( x < ( reference + size ) );
    }

    return function( draggable, droppable, toleranceMode, event ) {

        if ( !droppable.offset ) {
            return false;
        }

        var x1 = ( draggable.positionAbs ||
                draggable.position.absolute ).left + draggable.margins.left,
            y1 = ( draggable.positionAbs ||
                draggable.position.absolute ).top + draggable.margins.top,
            x2 = x1 + draggable.helperProportions.width,
            y2 = y1 + draggable.helperProportions.height,
            l = droppable.offset.left,
            t = droppable.offset.top,
            r = l + droppable.proportions().width,
            b = t + droppable.proportions().height;
        if (toleranceMode instanceof Function) {

            return toleranceMode(draggable, droppable, x1, x2, y1, y2, l, r, t, b);

        } else {
            switch ( toleranceMode ) {
                case "fit":
                    return ( l <= x1 && x2 <= r && t <= y1 && y2 <= b );
                case "intersect":
                    return ( l < x1 + ( draggable.helperProportions.width / 2 ) && // Right Half
                x2 - ( draggable.helperProportions.width / 2 ) < r && // Left Half
                t < y1 + ( draggable.helperProportions.height / 2 ) && // Bottom Half
                y2 - ( draggable.helperProportions.height / 2 ) < b ); // Top Half
                case "pointer":
                    return isOverAxis( event.pageY, t, droppable.proportions().height ) &&
                isOverAxis( event.pageX, l, droppable.proportions().width );
                case "touch":
                    return (
                ( y1 >= t && y1 <= b ) || // Top edge touching
                ( y2 >= t && y2 <= b ) || // Bottom edge touching
                ( y1 < t && y2 > b ) // Surrounded vertically
            ) && (
                ( x1 >= l && x1 <= r ) || // Left edge touching
                ( x2 >= l && x2 <= r ) || // Right edge touching
                ( x1 < l && x2 > r ) // Surrounded horizontally
            );
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    };
} )();
```

Then this, where you don't change anything, you just redefine them exactly the same way.

```
$.ui.ddmanager.drag = function( draggable, event ) {

    // If you have a highly dynamic page, you might try this option. It renders positions
    // every time you move the mouse.
    if ( draggable.options.refreshPositions ) {
        $.ui.ddmanager.prepareOffsets( draggable, event );
    }

    // Run through all droppables and check their positions based on specific tolerance options
    $.each( $.ui.ddmanager.droppables[ draggable.options.scope ] || [], function() {

        if ( this.options.disabled || this.greedyChild || !this.visible ) {
            return;
        }

        var parentInstance, scope, parent,
            intersects = intersect( draggable, this, this.options.tolerance, event ),
            c = !intersects && this.isover ?
                "isout" :
                ( intersects && !this.isover ? "isover" : null );
        if ( !c ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( this.options.greedy ) {

            // find droppable parents with same scope
            scope = this.options.scope;
            parent = this.element.parents( ":data(ui-droppable)" ).filter( function() {
                return $( this ).droppable( "instance" ).options.scope === scope;
            } );

            if ( parent.length ) {
                parentInstance = $( parent[ 0 ] ).droppable( "instance" );
                parentInstance.greedyChild = ( c === "isover" );
            }
        }

        // We just moved into a greedy child
        if ( parentInstance && c === "isover" ) {
            parentInstance.isover = false;
            parentInstance.isout = true;
            parentInstance._out.call( parentInstance, event );
        }

        this[ c ] = true;
        this[ c === "isout" ? "isover" : "isout" ] = false;
        this[ c === "isover" ? "_over" : "_out" ].call( this, event );

        // We just moved out of a greedy child
        if ( parentInstance && c === "isout" ) {
            parentInstance.isout = false;
            parentInstance.isover = true;
            parentInstance._over.call( parentInstance, event );
        }
    } );

}

$.ui.ddmanager.drop = function( draggable, event ) {

    var dropped = false;

    // Create a copy of the droppables in case the list changes during the drop (#9116)
    $.each( ( $.ui.ddmanager.droppables[ draggable.options.scope ] || [] ).slice(), function() {

        if ( !this.options ) {
            return;
        }
        if ( !this.options.disabled && this.visible &&
                intersect( draggable, this, this.options.tolerance, event ) ) {
            dropped = this._drop.call( this, event ) || dropped;
        }

        if ( !this.options.disabled && this.visible && this.accept.call( this.element[ 0 ],
                ( draggable.currentItem || draggable.element ) ) ) {
            this.isout = true;
            this.isover = false;
            this._deactivate.call( this, event );
        }

    } );
    return dropped;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u6wfj8mj/1/

Obviously, this one is a bit more prone to errors and there might be a better way to achieve this. Normally you could extend the widgets for example, which would be cleaner. But **intersect** and **ddmanager** are used both in **draggable** and **droppable** and are not directly in these widgets. So it's harder to extend in a clean way. 
You could also put the logic directly in drag event and drop event of you draggables and droppables, but since there's a default tolerance, not sure it's much better.

Comment: This looks great in the fiddle, thank you!, but I'm having implementation problems.  Why isn't it working here?  http://myingling.com/random/random/46519613/

Comment: @Bing It's because of the version of jquery ui. In the fiddle you had 1.9, in you example you have 1.12. I've edited to add a solution for 1.12.

Comment: This worked, thank you!  For my own study purposes: is there a reference to the major differences between versions of jQuery/jQuery UI?  I'm surprised that 1.9 -> 1.12 would change this.

Comment: There are upgrade guides (here for example: https://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.12/) but the change on structure is not mentionned. I guess they're trying to make it more modular and more robust (which also means harder to customize in this case). In many cases this structure has advantages.

Answer (score 0):

How to make a jQuery UI’s Droppable accept a Draggable when it’s top left corner gets inside?
I created jquery.ui.droppable-patch.js for jQuery UI Droppable 1.9.2

```
(function ($, undefined) {
$.ui.intersect = function (draggable, droppable, toleranceMode) {
    if (!droppable.offset) return false;
    var x1 = (draggable.positionAbs || draggable.position.absolute).left, x2 = x1 + draggable.helperProportions.width,
        y1 = (draggable.positionAbs || draggable.position.absolute).top, y2 = y1 + draggable.helperProportions.height;
    var l = droppable.offset.left, r = l + droppable.proportions.width,
        t = droppable.offset.top, b = t + droppable.proportions.height;
    switch (toleranceMode) {
        case 'fit':
            return (l <= x1 && x2 <= r
            && t <= y1 && y2 <= b);
            break;
        case 'intersect':
            return (l < x1 + (draggable.helperProportions.width / 2) // Right Half
            && x2 - (draggable.helperProportions.width / 2) < r // Left Half
            && t < y1 + (draggable.helperProportions.height / 2) // Bottom Half
            && y2 - (draggable.helperProportions.height / 2) < b ); // Top Half
            break;
        case 'pointer':
            var draggableLeft = ((draggable.positionAbs || draggable.position.absolute).left + (draggable.clickOffset || draggable.offset.click).left),
                draggableTop = ((draggable.positionAbs || draggable.position.absolute).top + (draggable.clickOffset || draggable.offset.click).top),
                isOver = $.ui.isOver(draggableTop, draggableLeft, t, l, droppable.proportions.height, droppable.proportions.width);
            return isOver;
            break;
        case 'touch':
            return (
                    (y1 >= t && y1 <= b) || // Top edge touching
                    (y2 >= t && y2 <= b) || // Bottom edge touching
                    (y1 < t && y2 > b)      // Surrounded vertically
                ) && (
                    (x1 >= l && x1 <= r) || // Left edge touching
                    (x2 >= l && x2 <= r) || // Right edge touching
                    (x1 < l && x2 > r)      // Surrounded horizontally
                );
            break;

        case "top-left-touch":
            return ( y1 >= t && y1 <= b ) && ( x1 >= l && x1 <= r );
        case "top-right-touch":
            return ( y1 >= t && y1 <= b ) && ( x2 >= l && x2 <= r );
        case "bottom-left-touch":
            return ( y2 >= t && y2 <= b ) && ( x1 >= l && x1 <= r );
        case "bottom-right-touch":
            return ( y2 >= t && y2 <= b ) && ( x2 >= l && x2 <= r );
        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }
};
```

}(jQuery));