# How to make a Jquery UI's Droppable accept a Draggable when its top left corner gets inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

After some testing, my [Droppable](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/) elements only accept [Draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) elements when the center of the Draggable is in the Droppable.

How can I change this behavior to accept a Draggable when its top left corner is inside a Droppable?

**NOTE:** The Draggables are larger than the Droppables.

Comment: I figure there is something in the API i am not seeing

Comment: @AlonEitan The question probably lacks some evidence of what he has been actually testing, but I think it is quite clear as long as you are familiar with jQuery UI's jargon ([Draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [Droppable](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/), in this case). I will edit it to try to make it a bit more clear though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some of the non-default values of [droppable's `tolerance` option](https://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-tolerance) can be a good alternative for you, although they will not do exactly what you are asking for.

From the docs:

> Specifies which mode to use for testing whether a draggable is hovering over a droppable. Possible values:
>
> - `"fit"`: Draggable overlaps the droppable entirely.
> - `"intersect"`: Draggable overlaps the droppable at least 50% in both directions.
> - `"pointer"`: Mouse pointer overlaps the droppable.
> - `"touch"`: Draggable overlaps the droppable any amount.

The default one is `"intersect"`. I would consider using either `"pointer"` or `"touch"`.

Alternatively, if you really need to use the top left corner as a reference, then you should overwrite `$.ui.intersect`, which is the function that takes care of checking whether a dragabble and a droppable intersect, based on the tolerance mode. It should return `true` if they do or `false` otherwise. It looks something like this:

```
$.ui.intersect = function (draggable, droppable, toleranceMode) {

    swtich(toleranceMode) {
        // Check if they intersect based on the selected mode.
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

You need to redefine that function and add a custom `case` block, while keeping the original modes as well. Otherwise, some other parts of the code that depend on that (maybe some other jQuery UI components), will break.

However, that will only work for jQuery UI < `1.12`. If you are using a newer version, you will have to overwrite some other methods. You can find a detailed answer with code examples of that here: [Build the matching option for jQuery UI Droppable's Intersect tolerance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46519613/build-the-matching-option-for-jquery-ui-droppables-intersect-tolerance)

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question, this is what I was looking for though! Thanks!

Comment: This is the correct answer.  I was looking for the same.  "pointer" is what you are looking for. It triggers droppable on the droppable element that is underneath the cursor when you drop the draggable.  When your drag element is bigger than the droppable element it can be hard to move the center into the droppable.  Especially when you are using a containment element and trying to move it to an edge.